# How to have multiple hover classes on a single text class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to use the least amount of CSS to create a single text `class` like this:

```
.film_tex {     
    font-family: 'CenturyGothicRegular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    color:#BFBFBF;  
}
```

Be able to use that `class` multiple times in html body.  But have unique `:hover` classes for each

```
.film_tex:hover { 
    color:#5F75C9;
}
```

I could just create multiple versions of the .film_tex style, like film_tex_01, film_tex_02 etc... with corresponding hover classes.  But I was thinking there must be a better way.

Like this:

```
<div class="film_tex" style="UNIQUE HOVER CLASS 01">NAME</div>
<div class="film_tex" style="UNIQUE HOVER CLASS 02">HELLO</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use additional classes which you apply to the different HTML tags as a second class which have those different hover styles, like

```css
.film_tex {     
    font-family: 'CenturyGothicRegular', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    color:#BFBFBF;  
}

.ho1:hover { 
    color:#5F75C9;
}


.ho2:hover { 
    color:#ff03aa;
}
```

```html
<div class="film_tex ho1">NAME</div>
<div class="film_tex ho2">HELLO</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you could use the :nth-of-type selector. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

```
.film_tex:nth-of-type(1):hover {
  color:#5F75C9;
}

.film_tex:nth-of-type(2):hover {
   color:#ff03aa;
}
```